# How to launch a program as administrator with Desktop Bridge

Tags: uac, desktop-bridge

I have a program, which users sometimes want to restart with administrative privileges to perform administrative tasks.
Currently, it has a menu item, which does the following call:

```
Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo("self.exe") { Verb = "runas" })
```

That works if program is installed with MSI. It displays a usual UAC prompt, which lets user to elevate the program.

However, when converted using Desktop Bridge converter, and installed the Store way, this call crashes due to insufficient privileges. Is there another way for me to (re-)start self with UAC prompt?

Alternatively, is it possible to perform elevation using COM?

I am on release branch, Creators Update btw

Comment: Desktop Bridge apps cannot elevate automatically, that is intended behavior from MSFT. Even their own Desktop Bridge apps do not elevate automatically, for example the Desktop App Converter (form the store).  The only solution is for the end user to elevate your app manually.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there another way for me to (re-)start self with UAC prompt?

No. According to this page (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-prepare, look for **Your app requires UIAccess**), it seems that *requesting the UAC prompt from your app is not currently supported.*

Remember, as a UWP app, it needs to work while running as the `interactive user`.

There is a one-year-old post from MSDN that answers a similar question: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a35b4c70-5fc6-4f1a-b80a-b11ee90105eb/uwpdesktop-bridgeproject-centennial-appconverter-convert-admin-apps?forum=wpdevelop

> Alternatively, is it possible to perform elevation using COM?

Given the findings above, the answer is probably no.

If I were in your position, I would rethink these `Administrative tasks`. They might even be something that you would not be able to run as a UWP app anyways. For instance, any attempt to create an HKLM key will fail.

Comment: My app's main purpose is to manage (positions of) open windows, so if user wants to move windows of some apps, that are elevated, he needs to run my app elevated as well. When it is installed as a store app, he can still right-click and pick "Run as Administrator" to do that, but that is less convenient than doing it from app or hotkey.

Comment: I just realized, that this was not a valid answer: in the link you mentioned first, it talks about an app requiring UIAccess through UAC manifest, which is not the case for my app. My app does not require access, but I want to give user an option to restart app with it.

Comment: My answer covers a more generic case. Apps cannot request the UAC prompt. Elevated apps will not be accepted in the store. Thus, there is no way of asking or giving your user an option to restart the app with it, as this is not a supported use case. Perhaps, the best alternative is to guide your user on how to run the app with elevated access manually.